# Нужно построить график с датами&

Tags: java, android, график

Доброго времени суток. Я в приложении использую GraphView для построения графика. мне необходимо чтобы по оси Х были даты, а не положительные и отрицательные числа. как это сделать?  Какие строки необходимо добавить?

Comment: полагаю, что в вашем датасете нужно вместо цифер вставить даты

Comment: хорошо, так как это сделать?

Comment: Так как это сделать?